# Embed a Flash INLINE inside HTML

Tags: html, flash

I'd like to embed a small flash file inside HTML, and I need to do  so INLINE, if it were a image, I would do something like..

```
<IMG SRC="data:image/gif;base64,RAAAtuhhx4dbgYKAAA7...more data....." ALT="could not load">
```

The file is [this one](http://raw.github.com/flockonus/TwitterCanTalk/master/public/9000player.swf)

How can I do that, assuming I can?

Comment: Inline? What do you mean by this exactly..

Answer (score -1):

http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashhtmlcode.php

This what you looking for?

Comment: No, I need to embed it inline, likely using the attribute data=